# How can i integrate Bootstrap template into magento

Tags: magento-1.9, template, custom-options, design

I need to integrate bootstrap template into magento,

Bootstrap template : http://obaju.ondrejsvestka.cz/

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for ways to do this by yourself but I would suggest checking out below suggested links. I have not implemented it myself but here in some they explain step by step.

Here are some of the links which might help you:

1. [Adding Bootstrap theme template files to your custom Magento theme](https://delboy1978uk.wordpress.com/2015/06/05/adding-bootstrap-theme-template-files-to-your-custom-magento-theme/)
2. [Bootstrap Responsive Theme](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bootstrap-responsive-theme.html)
3. [How to use Bootstrap in magento](http://howwhywhat.in/how-to-use-bootstrap-in-magento)
4. [Creating a Magento Reponsive Theme with Twitter Bootstrap](http://kimberelyt.com/magento-tutorials/day-1-creating-a-magento-reponsive-theme-with-twitter-bootstrap)
5. [Introducing Magento Boilerplate - a Twitter Bootstrap 3 Powered, HTML5, Mobile First Starter Theme!](http://www.webcomm.com.au/blog/2013/09/introducing-magento-boilerplate-a-twitter-bootstrap-3-powered-html5-mobile-first-starter-theme)

Comment: How to add bootstrap for my CMS page?

Comment: How to add bootstrap for Magento 1.9 CMS page? Arjun